# Удаление Activity из ОЗУ Android

Tags: android, bitmap, picasso

Я работаю с приложением, которое требует загрузки множества изображений из интернета. Использую 2 библиотеки: Fresco от Facebook и Picasso (В разных `Activity`). Но постоянно при использовании тестерами приложения появляется `OutOfMemory`. Есть идея завершать `Activity` сразу после выхода из нее. `finish()` вместе с `startActivityToResult(...)` не помогают. Пробовал еще `System.gс()`.

Приложение вылетает после занятой памяти в 60 Мб. Подскажите, что делать?

Comment: Да у вас там память жрет не активити а битмапы. Надо их очищать bitmap.recycle(). А activity и по finish() нормально завершается.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

`GC` Сам отработает когда оно понадобится. Настройте загрузку изображения в память - выставьте `RGB_565` в купе с загрузкой изображения по размеру вьюхи, а не оригинал изображения.

Я не работал с `Picasso` и `Fresco`, но на примере `Universal-Image-Loader` могу сказать вот так.

```
 DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(android.R.color.transparent)
                .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565) // уменьшаем количество битов на пиксель.
                .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT) // кратное уменьшение изображения под размеры view для экономии памяти.
                .cacheInMemory(true)
                .cacheOnDisk(true)
                .build();
```

Все это дико экономит память. И да, Есть у вас есть лапша между активностями `GC` не спасет.